# Selected ComboBoxItem image is not changing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have this `ComboBox` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboMeetingWeek" ItemsSource="{Binding Meetings}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Meeting, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Images/Bell.png" Margin="0,0,5,0"
                       Visibility="{Binding DisplayBellImage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}" Stretch="None"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateMeetingAsText}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And I have this `ContextMenu` that I am working on implementing (a work in progress):

```
<Image Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Source="Images\event_time.png" Margin="2">
    <Image.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Set Special Event" Command="{Binding SetSpecialEventCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit Special Event" Command="{Binding EditSpecialEventCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove Special Event">
                <MenuItem.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Meeting.IsSpecialEvent}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.Style>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Image.ContextMenu>
</Image>
```

Ignoring **Remove Special Event** for now.

Here are the two associated **Commands**:

```
_SetSpecialEventCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
    (s) =>
    {
        SpecialEventWindow windowEvent = new SpecialEventWindow();
        windowEvent.DataContext = this;
        windowEvent.ShowDialog();
        if (windowEvent.DialogResult.HasValue && windowEvent.DialogResult.Value)
            _Meeting.IsSpecialEvent = true;
    },
    (s) => !_Meeting.IsSpecialEvent);

_EditSpecialEventCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
    (s) =>
    {
        SpecialEventWindow windowEvent = new SpecialEventWindow();
        windowEvent.DataContext = this;
        windowEvent.ShowDialog();
        if (windowEvent.DialogResult.HasValue && windowEvent.DialogResult.Value)
            _Meeting.IsSpecialEvent = true;
        else
            _Meeting.IsSpecialEvent = false;
    },
    (s) => _Meeting.IsSpecialEvent);
```

And, so that the `ContextMenu` will correctly set the menu states the next time around it does:

```
public Data.MeetingInfo.Meeting Meeting
{
    get { return _Meeting; }
    set
    {
        // Has the existing meeting object changed at all?
        if(_Meeting != null && _Meeting.IsDirty)
        {
            // Yes, so save it
            _Model.Serialize();
            _Meeting.MarkClean();
        }

        // Now we can update to new value
        if (value != null)
        {
            _Meeting = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Meeting");
            _SetSpecialEventCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            _EditSpecialEventCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}
private Data.MeetingInfo.Meeting _Meeting;
```

So my context menu now always matches the state of the current combo menu item.

But when I set a combo item as an event when it was not one before, the combo item does not update and add the image. I decided to set the ItemSource to also have an `UpdateTriggerSource=PropertyChanged`.

Then, I adjusted my listening event handler:

```
private void Meeting_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);

    if (e.PropertyName == "IsSpecialEvent" || e.PropertyName == "IsCircuitVisit")
        OnPropertyChanged("Meetings");
}
```

But that is not working right. The list shows it now with an icon but not the current item itself.

[image: No image]

[image]

What step am I missing?

In order to see it I must pick another menu item and then come back to it.

Thank you.

### Update

I changed my two Model properties:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool IsSpecialEvent
{
    get { return _SpecialEvent.Event; }
    set
    {
        _SpecialEvent.Event = value;
        MarkDirty();
        OnPropertyChanged("IsSpecialEvent");
        OnPropertyChanged("DisplayBellImage");
    }
}

[XmlIgnore]
public bool IsCircuitVisit
{
    get { return _SpecialEvent.CircuitVisit; }
    set
    {
        _SpecialEvent.CircuitVisit = value;
        MarkDirty();
        OnPropertyChanged("IsCircuitVisit");
        OnPropertyChanged("DisplayBellImage");
    }
}
```

They now also fire the DisplayBellImage and all seems good. But I did need to update the ItemSource the way that I did, right?

Comment: The visibility of the bell image seems to be driven by the value of a property called `DisplayBellImage`. I don't see you ever changing the value of that property or raising `PropertyChanged` for it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett NIce one! :) I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be using a theme for your UI. Remove the theme from the combobox to check if you can see your icon then. My personal suspect is your theme.

Comment: I doubt that you needed to raise PropertyChanged for Meetings (if that's what you mean), because if I understand your code correctly, you aren't changing the value of the property -- it's still the same collection it was. But you can very easily test that theory by commenting out that if statement. If the behavior doesn't change, it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Andrew, by "all seems good", are you saying that your problem here has been solved?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Technically, that `Meeting_PropertyChanged' event needed to raise all the `CanExecute` checks again, that is all. **But** I also still need to raise them again when selecting the next Meeting.

Comment: You seem to be raising those `CanExecuteChanged` events in the setter to `Meeting`, which looks correct to me (assuming that a change to the value of Meeting is what changes their ability to execute). I don't understand the role of `Meeting_PropertyChanged`. What class is it a member of? Is it the same class that `Meeting` is a property of?

Comment: Yes. It is a listner for changes to the source.

Comment: I can see it's a "listener for changes to the source", but who is listening? It is a member of a class, but which class is it a member of? Is it a member of your viewmodel? Is your viewmodel listening to its own changes?

Comment: @EdPlunkett The ViewModel is listening for changes (ironically) that it has made to the source. So it can notify the view. Sounds like all I need to is not listen and just do selective onpropertychanged calls.

Comment: @EdPlunkett It is the ViewModel. But the ViewModel has a meeting property. It is the meeting property listening to changes to source.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Ahh, now I understand. That does make sense. I was wondering why it didn't recurse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visibility of the bell image seems to be driven by the value of a property called `DisplayBellImage`. I don't see you ever changing the value of that property, or raising `PropertyChanged` for it. You should be  calling `OnPropertyChanged("DisplayBellImage");` every time the value of `DisplayBellImage` changes.